# SQL query to show data that exactly match criteria in another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, ms-access

By this time I am implementing a system that perform matching between 3 tables and I am really need your help by now, suppose I have the following three tables:

**Table1: Relation between name and item**

```sql
User        Item
=====================
John Doe    Apple
John Doe    Orange
John Doe    Cat
John Doe    Dog
John Doe    Fish
Anna Sue    Apple
Anna Sue    Orange
Robinson    Banana
Robinson    Vessel
Robinson    Car
```

**Table2: To categorized the item**

```
Item Type   Item
==================
Fruit       Apple
Fruit       Orange
Fruit       Banana
Animal      Cat
Animal      Dog
Vehicle     Vessel
Vehicle     Car
Vehicle     Truck
```

**Table3: Matching of Item**

```
Match ID    Item Type
======================
M001        Fruit
M001        Animal
M002        Fruit
M002        Vehicle
```

All I want to ask that how I could only show all users that having all criteria that exactly match with the designated match ID 
For this case user **John Doe** that fulfill all criterias of having Item within the *Fruit* And *Animal* that relationship designated in the **Match ID** with the following format:

```
User            Match ID    Item Type   Item
================================================
John Doe        M001        Fruit       Apple
John Doe        M001        Fruit       Orange
John Doe        M001        Animal      Cat
John Doe        M001        Animal      Dog
Robinson        M002        Fruit       Banana
Robinson        M002        Vehicle     Vessel
Robinson        M002        Vehicle     Car
```

All solutions are highly appreciated, therefore thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, but actually only table1 - table3 the other one is only for example result table. I need the logic of query that can accommodate all data from 3 tables above to generate the results like the example result table at the end of my post.

Comment: In your Output table Rows for `Anna Sue` doesn't contains. Is there any condition for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For MySQL**

[**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b143/36)

```
select t1.User,t3.MatchID,t3.ItemType as ItemType,t2.Item as Item 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Item = t2.Item
inner join Table3 t3 on t3.ItemType = t2.ItemType
inner join
(select user,MatchID
from 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ItemType ORDER BY ItemType) AS typesTomatch , MatchID
FROM Table3 GROUP BY MatchID) abc
inner join
(Select a.User, group_concat(distinct b.ItemType ORDER BY b.ItemType)
as typesofpeople
from Table1 As a
inner join Table2 As b on a.Item = b.Item
group by a.User order by b.ItemType) def
on abc.typesTomatch = def.TYPESOFPEOPLE) xyz
on xyz.User = t1.User and xyz.MatchID = t3.MatchID;
```

Comment: This one works for me, I will let you know if I have any problem with the logic you provided later. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, but this is going to be a light dimming query on large sets.

[**SQL Fiddle demo here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63cd2/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63cd2/1)

```
SELECT ui.user_name
     , tm.match_id
     , tm.item_type
     , ui.item
  FROM (SELECT uu.user_name
             , tm.match_id
             , COUNT(DISTINCT tm.item_type) AS cnt_item_type
          FROM (SELECT u.user_name FROM user_item u GROUP BY u.user_name) uu
         CROSS
          JOIN type_match tm
         GROUP BY uu.user_name, tm.match_id 
       ) n
  JOIN (SELECT hui.user_name
             , htm.match_id
             , COUNT(DISTINCT htm.item_type) AS cnt_item_type
          FROM user_item hui
          JOIN item_type hit ON hit.item = hui.item
          JOIN type_match htm ON htm.item_type = hit.item_type
         GROUP BY hui.user_name, htm.match_id
       ) h
    ON h.cnt_item_type = n.cnt_item_type
   AND h.match_id      = n.match_id
   AND h.user_name     = n.user_name
  JOIN user_item ui
    ON ui.user_name = h.user_name
  JOIN item_type it
    ON it.item = ui.item
  JOIN type_match tm
    ON tm.item_type = it.item_type
   AND tm.match_id = h.match_id
 ORDER
    BY ui.user_name
     , tm.match_id
     , tm.item_type
     , ui.item
```

The inline view aliased as **`n`** represents what a user needs to have, all the item_type that are required in order to satisfy each match_id.

The inline view aliased as **`h`** represents what user actually has, all of the item_type that user has for each match_id.

We can get a count of the distinct item_type in each of those sets, and compare the counts. If the count is equal, then we know the user has all of the required item_type for that match_id.

Finally, we can join that back to the item a user actually has, so we can display a result.

(Again, this is going to be horrendous light dimmer, although indexes will help some.)

Comment: This one works for me, I will let you know if I have any problem with the logic you provided later. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT [User],  [Match ID], [Item Type],[Item]
From table1 
Inner join table2 on table1.item = table2.item
Inner join table3 on table2.[item type]= table3.[item type]
Where [User] = 'SOME USER NAME' AND table2.[item type] = 'SOME ITEM TYPE' AND table1.Item = 'SOME ITEM'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, anyway I don't want to limit the user only for 'John Doe', since the data also huge. Means I want to show all users that match criteria from those 3 tables.

Comment: So what's the criteria you want? Can you describe?

Comment: I'm leaving now I can contact you only in aome 5 hours

Comment: it's okay, I will wait for you.

Comment: @AlvinFuryadi are you still around, would you want to go on or did you get an satisfactory answer?

Comment: No, I don't want to limit the criteria in where. Is it possible to obtain all result?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, its worked :

```
select t1.[User],t3.matchid,t3.item_type,t1.item from table3 t3 left join table2 t2 on t3.item_type=t2.Item_type left join table1 t1 on t2.Item=t1.Item    where t1.[user]='JohnDoe' and t3.MatchId='m001' group by t1.[user],t1.item,t3.MatchId,t3.Item_Type
```

Comment: What if I want to select all users that match with the Match ID?

Comment: Check this one  ;  

select t1.[User],t3.matchid,t3.item_type,t1.item from table3 t3 left join table2 t2 on t3.item_type=t2.Item_type left join table1 t1 on t2.Item=t1.Item    where t1.[user]='JohnDoe' and t3.MatchId='m001' or  t1.[User]='robinson' and t3.MatchId='m002'    group by t1.[user],t1.item,t3.MatchId,t3.Item_Type

Answer (score 0):

You have a flaw in table3: 2 IDs (assuming itemtype is going to be the foreign key) for 1 data ( fruit ), otherwise the query would be:

```
select *
from table1 
   join table2 using (item)
   join table3 using (itemtype)
```

assuming, of course

1. itemtype is table 2 primary key
2. itemtype is table 3 foreign key to table 2
3. item is table 1 foreign key to table 2

Comment: this is not op asks for?

Comment: what do you mean by that question?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. (If it was intended to be answer, it does not really answer the question that was asked.) There is no "flaw in table3". That table is clearly an association table, to resolve a many-to-many relationship, between "match" and "itemtype".

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for explanation. I just didn't understand why two IDs could be assigned to one item.